# How to properly evaluate an evaluated ERB template that contains Ruby code?

Tags: ruby, erb

Say for example I have a file which is a ERB template containing Ruby code:

```
module <%= @name %>
  class Client
    # ...
  end
end
```

I want to evaluate the ERB code, and then I want to evaluate what I get back.

```
@name = 'Jimi'
erb = ERB.new('module <%= @name %> end')
eval(erb.result)
Jimi.class
  # => Module
```

I want to have multiple template of such code in separate files (which I guess would have a `.rb.erb` extension) but I do not know how to approach this problem in a way that follows good practice and works well. I want to use this as an alternative to complicated metaprogramming that would have to be done otherwise. Is this a good alternative? *Of course the problems would be a lot more complicated, not just simple dynamic module creation.* Is there a better way of evaluating the result of an evaluated ERB file?

Just as a sidenote, I am developing a project which relies heavily on metaprogramming at the moment as it has to create modules, classes, and methods dynamically. It is named Hendrix and I am currently working on version [1.0.0](https://github.com/rafalchmiel/hendrix/tree/1.0.0) where I want to improve the way I am currently doing my generations and I think templates such as these are the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

ERB strikes me as a bit of a hack in this situation. Ruby has built-in string formatting if all you need to do is simple substitution:

```
template = "module %{name} end"
eval(template % {name: Jimi})
Jimi.class
# => Module
```

See [`String#%`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/String.html#method-i-25).

Comment: In this particular situation, yes it does. I will be creating methods (lot's of methods) and other stuff like `attr_accessor` (etc.) so I thought a ERB approach would be best. Is the example I gave the best way to approach this or is there something more "best practice-sy"? I can't seem to find any examples of templating like that on GitHub.

Comment: By "in this situation" I mean where string substitution is sufficient for your purposes. ERB allows for embedding of arbitrary Ruby code (control flow, etc.), which would be serious overkill if you don't need it - even if it's "lot's of" substitutions.

Answer (score 0):

The use of `eval` with user input is considered a security concern. Consider using metaprogramming in order to achieve your goal.

```
class_name = 'Jimi'  # read this data from a file

new_class = Class.new do
  class Client
    # ...
  end
end

Object.const_set class_name, new_class
```

Using metaprogramming, it is possible to create modules and classes as well as define methods in a way such that running arbitrary code is not necessary.

Comment: "I want to use this as an alternative to complicated metaprogramming that would have to be done otherwise."
This leads me to think that the asker has already considered your approach.